# TwoWay Binding a DateTime To a TextBox - Year only

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, binding

How can I bind (TwoWay) a DateTime to a TextBox such that only the Year of the DateTime is displayed and the TextBox accepts input as a Year as well (i.e. User can type "2014" and this will bind successfully to the DateTime)?

I have the following:

```
TextBox Margin="10, 1" MinWidth="100" Text="{Binding LastGoodDate, StringFormat={}{0:yyyy}}" >
```

Which successfully shows the DateTime in yyyy format, however the binding fails when the user types "2014".

I can get around this by binding instead to an intermediate string property, and then manually parsing the result and storing it in the DateTime, but I would like to avoid this if possible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably easiest to do this in the view-model, by adding a separate "Year" property.  Eg:

```
TextBox Text="{Binding LastGoodYear}" >
```

The property should not have its own backing field, but should modify the date as needed:

```
public int LastGoodYear
{
    get 
    {
        return LastGoodDate.Year; 
    }
    set
    {
        LastGoodDate = new DateTime(value, LastGoodDate.Month, LastGoodDate.Day);
    }
}
```

Also make sure to trigger "PropertyChanged" (LastGoodYear) in the "LastGoodDate" setter.

Comment: Thanks, this is sort of what I was hoping to avoid (a backing property representing the year), but I will mark it as answered, because I ended up going with something like this.

Comment: @D.Reagan I imagine that you could avoid the backing property by using a MultiBinding with a converter -- but the extra property seems more straightforward.